# Como adicionar itens vindo de um JSON, em uma base de dados?

Tags: c#, json

Explicando:
Tenho as seguintes classes para trabalhar, uma que é a chegada e o retorno do JSON e outras, entities data, segue abaixo:

UsuarioExperimentoResult:

```
public class UsuarioExperimentoResult
{
    public string nome_usuario_experimento { get; set; }
    public string telefone_experimento { get; set; }
    public string email_experimento { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; internal set; }
    public List<EnderecoExperimento> endereco_expermento { get; set; }

}
```

Entity Data:

```
public class QuemAvisarExperimento : EntityData
{
    public string id_usuario_experimento_quem_avisar { get; set; }
    public string id_endereco_experimento_quem_avisar { get; set; }
    public string nome_experimento_quem_avisar { get; set; }
    public string telefone_experimento_quem_avisar { get; set; }
}

public class EnderecoExperimento : EntityData
{
    public string id_usuario_experimento { get; set; }
    public string nome_endereco_experimento { get; set; }
    public string destino_experimento { get; set; }
    public double lat_endereco_experimento { get; set; }
    public double lng_endereco_experimento { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioExperimento : EntityData
{
    public string nome_usuario_experimento { get; set; }
    public string telefone_experimento { get; set; }
    public string email_experimento { get; set; }

}
```

Então, eu recebo o JSON e adiciono o usuário, crio um ID para ele e feito isso, devo adicionar os itens que vieram na lista do tipo `EnderecoExperimento`. Como eu posso fazer isso, adicionar item a item, na base de dados e relacionado ao ID do usuárioi criado anteriormente?

Segue aqui, o método que criei mas, não tem dado certo:

```
private HttpResponseMessage operacaoPost(UsuarioExperimentoResult usuarioExperimentoResult)
{
    mContext context = new mContext();
    if (usuarioExperimentoResult != null)
    {
        // Adding User
        UsuarioExperimento usuario = new UsuarioExperimento
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), //id para novo cadastro
            nome_usuario_experimento = usuarioExperimentoResult.nome_usuario_experimento,
            telefone_experimento = usuarioExperimentoResult.telefone_experimento,
            email_experimento = usuarioExperimentoResult.email_experimento
        };

        context.UsuarioExperimentoDB.Add(usuario);

        // Adding Address
        if (usuarioExperimentoResult.endereco_expermento != null)
        {
            List<EnderecoExperimento> enderecoExperimentos = new List<EnderecoExperimento>();
            enderecoExperimentos = usuarioExperimentoResult.endereco_expermento;
            foreach (var end in usuarioExperimentoResult.endereco_expermento)
            {
                //gerar um id para cada endereço
                end.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            }

        }
        // Saving the changes
        context.SaveChanges();
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, RequestResponseUtils.createResponseBody(usuario));
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "404");
    }
}
```

Obrigado!

Edit:

json:

```
{
    "dados":{"nome_usuario_experimento":"teste",
             "telefone_experimento":"0123456789",
             "email_experimento":"teste@teste",
             "endereco_expermento":[{"nome_endereco_experimento":"nome1",
                                      "destino_experimento":"destino1"
             }]
            }
}
```

Comment: seria bom mostra o json também, mas normalmente vc deserializa em um objeto do tipo `UsuarioExperimento ` no seu caso, e dentro dele a lista de endereços já vem populada. ao adicionar pelo entity, ele mesmo já insere os endereços

Comment: O endereço tem de vincular o Id do usuário nele, por isso eu salvo o usuário antes do endereço. E, eu não entendi como resolver. Meu foreach ali, como acesso os atributos da Classe Endereço para colocar em cada item da base de dados? tais como o nome, o endereço e etc. O usuário não tem chave estrangeira, o controle é todo feito no código.

Comment: o entity faz isso... basta vocÊ colocar um objeto usuario dentro do endereço

Comment: @RovannLinhalis somente um get; set; do tipo usuário dentro do entity endereço resolve o problema? No controller eu coloco o entity endereço recebendo a lista? isso? Coloque como resposta e eu marco como correta. obrigado!

Comment: Json esta no edit da pergunta